# Get Microsoft Communicator status

Tags: .net, office-communicator, user-presence

I'd like to add Communicator Presence to my application (much like how Outlook and other MS apps have it), and I'm unable to find documentation about how to fetch this status.

Is there a way I can query the Live Communicator server for a person's status? If there are docs out there and I just can't find them, please give me a pointer in that direction, and I'll go away with my tail between my legs for not searching hard enough...

**UPDATE:**
The API provided requires Communicator Server 2007, but we're still using 2003. Is there an older version of the API out there? All the downloads I can find on the MSFT site require 2007. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you will need to use the RTC Client API for LCS 2003/2005 - more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms775893.aspx)

The Live Communications Server 2003 MSDN documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa167872(office.11).aspx)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

This looks promising: [Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 Presence Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=25A27453-15FF-48AB-AF1B-692CD77AB510&displaylang=en)

Comment: This is for Communicator 2007, and we're still using 2003. Is there an older version? Microsoft doesn't make it easy to download one, if there is...